# Python on Win7: matching screen shots from 2 different PCs?

Tags: python, windows, screenshot, python-imaging-library

I use **Desktopmagic**  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Desktopmagic/14.3.11#downloads
with the following code to take small (50px by 50px) screen-shots using python:

```
from desktopmagic.screengrab_win32 import (
    getDisplayRects, saveScreenToBmp, saveRectToBmp, getScreenAsImage,
    getRectAsImage, getDisplaysAsImages)

def snap_shot(left_offset, top_offset, width, height, file_name):
    right=left_offset+width
    bottom=top_offset+height

    saveRectToBmp(file_name, rect=(left_offset, top_offset, right, bottom))
```

I also use **pillow** to compare screenshots to reference images

```
from PIL import Image

def compare_images(f1,f2):
    h1 = Image.open(f1).histogram()
    h2 = Image.open(f2).histogram()

    rms = math.sqrt(functools.reduce(operator.add,map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2, h1, h2))/len(h1))

    return rms
```

Everything worked fine until I tried to migrate the code and reference images to a new PC.
To the human eye there is no difference between the screenshots taken on PC1 and those taken on PC2, but my **compare_images** function sees a difference.

When looking for an exact match between a reference image taken on PC1 and a screen shot from PC2, the test fails.

So....what does it take for 2 Windows computers to render desktop windows identically?
I assume if they were Identical hardware, the screen shots would match 100%.  But what are the critical elements?   Would it be enough for both to have the same graphics card?   What factors do you think could come into play?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Two different machines may have different Operating System versions ( if not families ) and their GUI elements ( Window-borders, Window-icons, Window-TopFrameColouringScheme, Desktop Motives, Cursor-icon, Wallpaper-image/tile/scale factors and many more )

In case just the colour-depth settings is different ( for all the otherwise same / identical setup ), the resulting pixel-values do not match each other ( principally must not ). This case could be checked in the most simple way -- just compare the BMP files' ColourPALETTE contents for 32bit colour-depth vs. a reduced 16bit colour-depth in `f1` and `f2` files.